# How to implement a queue for bulk delivery

Tags: java, list, multithreading

I need to read tens of millions of rows of data and send it through an HTTP request.In order to reduce the number of HTTP requests and accelerate execution speed, I want to use a queue to cache the data, and then use a scheduled task to send every two seconds(the sending frequency is yet to be determined through testing),after sending the data, the queue need to cache data again for the next time.

Data is not continuously added, and there may be uncertain time intervals. However, data needs to be transmitted through HTTP in a timely manner, so I cannot determine whether it needs to be sent based on the number of data items in the queue. To ensure the timeliness of data transmission through HTTP, I can only use a timed transmission method.

I use `synchronized` to ensure thread safe,but this means that for every recod  added into the list  need `synchronized` first.

I would like to know if there is a more efficient or elegant implementation method.

This is my code.

Thanks a lot.

```
public class ProduceTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Producer producer = new Producer();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
           producer.push(String.valueOf(i));
        }
   }
}

class Producer{
    ScheduledExecutorService service = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
    final Object lock = new Object();
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    public Producer() {
        service.scheduleAtFixedRate(new ScheduleTask(), 0, 2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
    public void push(String str) {
        if (str!=null && str.length()>0) {
            synchronized (lock) {
                strings.add(str);
            }
        }
    }
    public void process(){
        synchronized (lock) {
            List<String> afterConvert = new ArrayList<>();
            for (String string : strings) {
                // String tmp = convert(string)
                // afterConvert.add(tmp);
            }
            // http sent afterConvert list
            strings = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }
    class ScheduleTask implements Runnable{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            process();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With your current design, `process` appears to hold the lock until all HTTP request is complete, assuming the the HTTP request occurs at the line `// http sent afterConvert list`.

This means that calls to `push` will block.

Instead you can rewrite `process` like this, so that it holds the lock only very briefly, and `push` can immediately start adding string to `strings`.

```
public void process() {
        List<String> toConvert;

        synchronized (lock) {
            // save the current list of Strings to convert and send
            toConvert = strings;
            // start recording Strings in a new batch
            strings = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        List<String> afterConvert = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String string : toConvert) {
            // String tmp = convert(string)
            // afterConvert.add(tmp);
        }
        // http sent afterConvert list
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The list is being modified at `push` method **only** so `updateListLock` is required to update the collection (since not using concurrent collection)

While the scheduler runs it copies the entire list and reset the new list to blank. We made the list volatile so that we maintain happens-before while reassigning list variable.

We need to have `resetListLock` to avoid issue if multiple `ScheduleTask` run in parallel.
Choice of ScheduledExecutorService needs to be revisited since the documentation says

> If any execution of this task takes longer than its period, then subsequent executions may start late, but will not concurrently execute.

```
class ProduceTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Producer producer = new Producer();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            producer.push(String.valueOf(i));
        }
    }
}

class Producer{
    ScheduledExecutorService service = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
    final Object resetListLock = new Object();
    final Object updateListLock = new Object();
    volatile List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    public Producer() {
        service.scheduleAtFixedRate(new ScheduleTask(), 0, 2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
    public void push(String str) {
        if (str!=null && str.length()>0) {
            synchronized (updateListLock) { //considering strings list is being updated here only
                strings.add(str);
            }
        }
    }

    public List<String> getAndResetProducerList() {
        List<String> newProducerList = new LinkedList<>();//since frequent operation is add and sequential read
        List<String> newConsumerList = null;

        synchronized (resetListLock){
            newConsumerList = strings;
            strings = newProducerList;
        }
        return newConsumerList;
    }


    public void process(){
        List<String> consumerList = getAndResetProducerList();
        List<String> afterConvert = new ArrayList<>();
            for (String string : consumerList) {
                // String tmp = convert(string)
                // afterConvert.add(tmp);
            }
            // http sent afterConvert list
    }
    class ScheduleTask implements Runnable{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            process();
        }
    }
}
```